# How to get x and y position of QTextCursor (not .position()) in QTextEdit?

Tags: qt

For example, I want pop-up window with a list of variables, as often there in code editors. For this i need know x and y position of QTextCursor in QTextEdit. But only function that seems reasonable is int QTextCursor::verticalMovementX () const. Why no QTextCursor::horisontalMovementX ()?

Comment: Same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583199/how-to-find-global-position-of-text-cursor

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is `QTextEdit::cursorRect()`